# nginx runs an subdomain to a new app with an existing website

Tags: nginx, gitlab

My server already  has an RoR app running on Nginx at port 80 , now I want to set the Gitlab in the same server,

Now, I have to access the Gitlab by `myserver:1987/`

If I want to a access the Gitlab by `myserver/gitlab`

How to achieve it ?

nginx.conf

```
http{
include /opt/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

...

server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

passenger_enabled on;
#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    index  index.html index.htm;
    root /home/poc/projects/zeus/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

sites-enabled/gitlab.conf

```
# GITLAB
# Maintainer: @randx

# CHUNKED TRANSFER
# It is a known issue that Git-over-HTTP requires chunked transfer encoding [0] which is not
# supported by Nginx < 1.3.9 [1]. As a result, pushing a large object with Git (i.e. a single large file)
# can lead to a 411 error. In theory you can get around this by tweaking this configuration file and either
# - installing an old version of Nginx with the chunkin module [2] compiled in, or
# - using a newer version of Nginx.
#
# At the time of writing we do not know if either of these theoretical solutions works. As a workaround
# users can use Git over SSH to push large files.
#
# [0] https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt#n99
# [1] https://github.com/agentzh/chunkin-nginx-module#status
# [2] https://github.com/agentzh/chunkin-nginx-module

upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen *:1987;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name dqa-test;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  # Increase this if you want to upload large attachments
  # Or if you want to accept large git objects over http
  client_max_body_size 5m;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /opt/nginx/logs/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /opt/nginx/logs/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }

  error_page 502 /502.html;
}
```